# C# Library class accessing a resource file

Tags: c#, directory

I recently made a API on AWS API Gateway. To make accessing it easier, I created a dev kit library to make accessing the Gateway methods easier (using .Net 6). To make getting the API URI's easier to access and store, I put all of the URI's into a json file in the library.

When doing unit testing on the library itself, everything passed. The library accesses the json file with the below code

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Resources\\config.json")))
            {
                json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

I published the library as a Nuget package and then installed it on a .Net web app. When the app tries calls a method from this dev kit, it throws the following error:

Message=Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Projects*ParentFolder**Subfolder**ProjectFolder*\Resources\config.json'

Which the file path given is the file path of the project, not the filepath that leads to the config.json file. So the question is, how do you structure the file path to access a file if it is in a library that is designed to be a stand alone library like a dev kit? Or is it just a bad idea and should I approach storing the URI's for the methods in a different manner?

FYI - the I do know the issue has nothing to do with the AWS API Gateway or Lambda functions. Those are running correctly and performing in a consistent manner.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

The current directory is a property of the process, which will be the application referencing the library. If you want the path of the library itself then I would think that something like this would do the job:

```cs
var rootFolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```